# Android setChunkedStreamingMode() not working as expected

Tags: android, networking, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpUrlConnection in Android to upload a large image to a server
Everything works so far, but the sending is a little bit slow...
I am using the setChunkedStreamingMode() method, so my older devices do not run out of memory while uploading the image. The Chunk size is currently set to 4MB

However, I looked into the Network Monitor of Android and noticed that I have a lot of small peaks, what is not what I expected
[image: Network Monitor]

As far as I understood, the OutputStream should read bytes in as long as the chunk size is not reached. When the chunk size is reached, the chunk will be sent to server as a whole. But I don
t get the little peaks in the Network Monitor
I guess I am missing something here?

Here is my code:

```
private final String boundary = "obzorBOUNDARYrozbo";
private final String mMimeType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private final String hyphens = "--";
private final String encoding = "utf-8";
private final String connectionType = "Keep-Alive";
```

...

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    // The body is sent in chunks of the defined size
    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(Settings.__SendFileChunkSize);
    // Allows us to handle the response in the InputStream
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    // Allows us to write to the OutputStream
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    // Disable the cache
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    // Sets the request method to POST
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    // Writes all Cookies written in the CookieManager to the header
    connection.setRequestProperty(
            "Cookie",
            TextUtils.join(";", cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies())
    );
    // The connection should be kept alive
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", connectionType);
    // Set the charset to UTF-8
    connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", encoding);
    // The type is defined to be a multipart request
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mMimeType);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
```

...

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(file),
            Settings.__SendFileBufferSize
    );

    // Check if less than maxBufferSize bytes are remaining
    int bytesAvailable = bis.available();
    // Do not read more bytes than maxBufferSize
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, Settings.__SendFileBufferSize);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    while (bis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize) > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = bis.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, Settings.__SendFileBufferSize);
    }
    bis.close();
    bis = null;
    buffer = null;
```

Here are my constants for the Chunk size and the buffer size

```
public static final int __SendFileChunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
public static final int __SendFileBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
```

The image I want to upload is ~8MB

Comment: Your copy loop is incorrect. The final parameter to the `write()` method should be the count returned by the `read()` method. All the code that calls `available()` and uses its result can simply be deleted. Just use a fixed size buffer, say 8k. 4MB is very large for a chunk size. 4k would be more like it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  
But I am still confused about that Chunk Size, am I right that the Chunk size determines when a part of my large file is sent to the server? And that this part is sent as a whole?